# localStorage persistance on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, html, web-applications

On IOS 5.1 Apple moved the location of localStorage-files to cache/temp directory, so iOS deleted the localStorage on own decision.

Does apple fixed this in later versions or are they alternatives for saving data persistant in Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fixed by apple in iOS6: http://blog.nsbasic.com/2012/09/important-io6-and-data-storage/